# Can I recycle ffmpeg2pass-0.log

Tags: ffmpeg

Can I re-use 2 pass logs?

That is to say: I *am* doing this, but I wonder if I *should* be doing this. ie: does a -pass 1 that had different crf/b:v parameters from -pass 2 output produce the same results as always uniquely encoding both passes for every input?
I have a feeling I shouldn't be reusing pass1.

Say I am doing tests, and for the same input file produce multiple 2 pass ouputs with varying constrained bitrate/crf variants...

eg:

> constrainedQ-br9M-crf12.webm
>
> constrainedQ-br12M-crf18.webm
>
> constrainedQ-br14M-crf18.webm
>
> constrainedQ-br16M-crf18.webm

Is it ok to detect the prior log file, check that it was produced for the same input file, and re-use it by skipping -pass 1 for subsequent renders? (in which case ffmpeg finds the existing log and appears to use it for pass 2)

Or

Should I be re-generating the pass 1 log whenever the bitrate or crf changes?

[edit] everyone loves a bit of context code

```
f_rm2passFilesVP9() {
    rm \
        "${input%/*}/ffmpeg2pass-0.log" \
        "${input%/*}/ffmpeg2pass-0.log.temp" \
        "${input%/*}/ffmpeg2pass-0.log.mbtree.temp" &> /dev/null
}
...
f_2passLogForThisInputExists() {
    if [[ "$input" == $(cat "${input%/*}/.priorInput" 2> /dev/null) ]];then
        echo 1
    else
        echo 0
    fi
}
...

if [[ 0 == $(f_2passLogForThisInputExists) ]];then
    echo " ENCODING CONSTRAINED QUALITY br:$br crf:$CRF - PASS 1/2"
    trap "f_rm2passFilesVP9" 1 2 3 6
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i "${input}" \
        -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 1 -b:v "$br" -crf "$CRF" -threads 4 \
        -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 \
        -an -f webm /dev/null
    echo "$input" >"${input%/*}/.priorInput"
    trap "" 1 2 3 6
else
    echo "REUSING - PASS 1 FOR THIS INPUT - PASS 1/2"
fi
echo "ENCODING CONSTRAINED QUALITY br:$br crf:$CRF - PASS 2/2"
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i "${input}" \
    -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 2 -b:v "$br" -crf "$CRF" -threads 4 -speed 2 \
    -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 \
    -c:a libopus -b:a 64k -f webm \
    "${exportName}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be OK if you are simply giving it more or less bitrate. I do this sometimes, but I also use a lot of zones, so I usually just rerun first pass because I know zones will definitely make a difference in the first pass file. If I add a zone after the first pass file is created the it will apply the difference in bitrate across the file and if I do it before then the zone bitrate modifier gets applied only to the frames specified.  Since I think you are simply giving the file more or less bitrate then the distribution should be pretty much the same.  I would say only rerun first pass if your second pass is going to much higher bitrate, like 20% or more.  Better just to run first pass at the highest bitrate you intend to encode, if possible.

Comment: Interesting. Can you cite anything I could read detailing this, or expand specific details? ie: What conditions do and don't warrant regenerating -pass1 and why?

Comment: I don't really have any documentation, but I have tested with specific files and looking at the bit rate distribution of the final output file you can tell running the first pass with a zone definitely has an impact equal to the zone value, while setting the zone after the first pass distributes the bits more evenly.  I don't have any data about drastic changes in bit rate from first pass to second pass, but I would guess if your first pass had significantly fewer bits to distribute then it would have a less accurate picture of what should happen in a second pass encoded with a much higher br.

Comment: So, I recently did some testing.  I compared an encode where the first pass bit rate was 9000k and second pass was encoded at 6000k.  Then I did another encode where first pass 6000k and second pass was also 6000k.  I looked at the SSIM and PSNR of the two files and the 9000k first pass was slightly better quality.  I was a little surprised, but I guess the higher bit rate actually does help a little.  It wasn't a big difference but I will not be using a first pass file with any less bit rate than I need for my second pass.